# template typename initialization

Tags: c++, templates, initialization, typename

```c++
template<typename Dati>
class NodoVettore
{
private:
  Dati valore;
public:
    NodoVettore()
    {
        valore = Dati();
    }

    NodoVettore(Dati nuovoValore)
    {
        valore = nuovoValore;
    }
};
```

Which is the differences between the two NodoVettore() constructors? 
Why should I use Dati() instead of a classical initialization?
Why do we have brackets after typename Dati in:

> valore = Dati()

Comment: These are questions better answered by reading a C++ text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first constructor is a default constructor, and from what you've shown us, it simply assigns some (I assume) member variable named valore to a default constructed object of type Dati.

Your second constructor is a conversion constructor (my terminology, not standard) that accepts an object of type Dati and assigns it to your member variable. I call it a conversion constructor because it is NOT marked with the `explicit` keyword.

The reason why you need the brackets after Dati in your default constructor is because that is just how you construct an object.

I hope this helps you, but I would advise you to get a good book on C++ that covers these fundamentals and more.